# Google cloud bucket, can't upload accented file name

Tags: php, utf-8, google-cloud-storage

I created a backup tool that uploads all my server files to a google cloud bucket with that code :

```
$sha256 = hash_file("sha256", $filepath);

$bucket->upload(fopen($filepath, 'r'), [
                        'name' => utf8_encode($filepath),
                        'metadata' => 
                        [
                            'metadata' => 
                            [
                                'sha256' => $sha256,
                            ]   
                        ]   
                    ]
            );
```

It works for most of the files but when there is an accent in the filename I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\BadRequestException: Malformed multipart body. in /var/www/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php on line 362
( ! ) Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\BadRequestException: Malformed multipart body. in /var/www/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php on line 362
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
4   12.1068 2043584 Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket->upload( )  .../backupall.php:190
5   12.1111 2060368 Google\Cloud\Core\Upload\MultipartUploader->upload( )   .../Bucket.php:293
6   12.1145 2074984 Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send( )   .../MultipartUploader.php:68
```

If I remove the utf8_encode I get another error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: json_encode error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in /var/www/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/JsonTrait.php on line 61
( ! ) InvalidArgumentException: json_encode error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in /var/www/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/JsonTrait.php on line 61
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
4   12.1204 2043576 Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket->upload( )  .../backupall.php:190
5   12.1247 2060360 Google\Cloud\Core\Upload\MultipartUploader->upload( )   .../Bucket.php:293
6   12.1250 2063728 Google\Cloud\Core\Upload\MultipartUploader::jsonEncode( )   .../MultipartUploader.php:42
```

EDIT: After the following tests I think it's a bug of the library, even by using a name without accent I have the same error and if I keep the name but change the file to another it works:

```
//this one doesn't work
$bucket->upload(fopen($filepath, 'r'), [
                        'name' => "testname",
                        'metadata' => 
                        [
                            'metadata' => 
                            [
                                'sha256' => $sha256,
                            ]   
                        ]   
                    ]
            );

//this one works
$bucket->upload(fopen("testfile", 'r'), [
                        'name' => utf8_encode($filepath),
                        'metadata' => 
                        [
                            'metadata' => 
                            [
                                'sha256' => $sha256,
                            ]   
                        ]   
                    ]
            );
```

That mean that the problem is that the `upload` function uses the filename (even if I send a file handler) and that I don't have any way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation PHP  utf8_encode()  Function:

> The utf8_encode() function encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8.

This means that any other format in ISO that the string is, will not be converted - which might be the case that you are facing - you can take a further look in this documentation Filename encoding and interoperability problems for erros related to filename encoding.

The official documentation from PHP - accessible here - indicates that in case your string is not in this ISO, you should use the method `iconv()` to convert your string - it might be worth it anyway, since this work similarly to the `utf8_encode()`.

I would recommend you to give it a try using the `iconv()` method, to confirm if it works. Examples such as the below one of the usage of this method, can be found on this other post from the Community here.

```
$filepath = iconv("utf-8", "<code from the string>", $filename);
```

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Please see my edit, the utf8_encode works for my file.

Comment: Hi @Entretoize indeed, considering your tests - thanks for editing it! - it seems that it's a problem with the library. I would recommend you to raise an issue/bug with Google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0) so they can track this and help you.